# multiple records in json update laravel database

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I have a problem when going through my array, it only updates me just one record and I would like to act everything since I want the order to change in my table

```
public function updateAll(Request $request)
{

    $questionOption1 = QuestionOption::all();

    foreach ($questionOption1 as $item) {
         $id=$item->id;
         foreach ($request->all() as $order1) {
            if ($order1['id'] == $id) {
                $item->update(['order' => $order1['order']]);
        }
    }
    return response('Update Successful.', 200);

}
// vuejs 
eupdate() {
  this.questionOptionNew.map((item,index)=>{
         item.order = index + 1 ;

  });

  var url = '/api/update';

   axios.post(url,this.questionOptionNew)
   .then(response=>{
      this.getQuestion();
    });
  console.log("hola",this.questionOptionNew);

},
```

[image]

Comment: Just to notify you, you have a syntax error in the `if()` statement in the second `foreach()` of the `updateAll()` function

Comment: give me a guide please

Comment: You're not closing the `if()` statement with a closing bracket `}`

Comment: foreach ($questionOption1 as $item) {
            $id=$item->id;
            foreach ($request->all() as $order1) {
               if ($order1->id == $id) {
                   $item->update(['order' => $order1['order']]);
           }
       }
     }

Comment: no tengo error codigo ya me funciono